# Creating Portfile from git repo using HEAD and/or origin/master? How to?

Tags: github, tcl, macports

There is very little documentation about how to create a Portfile using a github repo HEAD and pulling from origin/master or tag.

are checksums needed?  if so, how to calculate?

how to pull a PR from a different repo/fork?

for example

```
PortSystem          1.0

name                zimg
version             1.0
categories          multimedia

maintainers         nomaintainer

description         Colorspaces: SMPTE-C (NTSC)
homepage            https://github.com/sekrit-twc/zimg
distname            ${name}

fetch.type          git
git.url             https://github.com/sekrit-twc/zimg.git
git.branch          origin/master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to pull a PR from a different repo/fork?

If you have the ID of the PR, as mentioned in "[Checking out pull requests locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/)", the fetch URL would be

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

Applied to a [porfile, with `fetch.type` set to `git`](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/reference.phases.html#reference.phases.fetch.git), you can try as a branch name

```
git.branch          origin/pull/ID/head
```

---

As [neverpanic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2127896/neverpanic) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119988/creating-portfile-from-git-repo-using-head-and-or-origin-master-how-to/47120524#comment81230090_47120524):

> Note that while you can set `fetch.type git` and `git.branch origin/master`, this is not supported by MacPorts.
>   It's fine for development, but when trying to get a Portfile included in MacPorts, we expect that a certain version of the Portfile will always produce the same result, regardless of when you install it.
>
> For git submodules, add `post-fetch { system -W ${worksrcpath} "${git.cmd} submodule update --init" }` together with `fetch.type git`.

Comment: thanks for the help.  do you how in this Portfile do I fetch and pull submodules?

Comment: That I don't know: try asking a new question for this specific point.

Comment: Note that while you can set `fetch.type git` and `git.branch origin/master`, this is not supported by MacPorts. It's fine for development, but when trying to get a Portfile included in MacPorts, we expect that a certain version of the Portfile will always produce the same result, regardless of when you install it. For git submodules, add `post-fetch { system -W ${worksrcpath} "${git.cmd} submodule update --init" }` together with `fetch.type git`.

Comment: @neverpanic Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.